# App.Config file not working as expected with Selenium c#

Tags: .net, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I am attempting to use app.config for commonly used values and I cannot get the values into the browser. As far as my code is concerned its fine, no issues according to my previous research however it simply returns the value but doesnt use it in the browsers URL.

Code within test: 
`string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["URL"].ToString();`

App.config:

`<add key="URL" value="https://www.google.co.uk"/>`

the config is sat amongst the usual   etc so i know its not because of case sensitive mistakes.

Comment: So you assign the value to the `URL` variable. Can you post the code where you use this variable? If you are only assigning a value to it and never *using* the variable, then *that* is your problem.

Comment: I presumed it wasnt as easy as the above, what would I need to do to now use that URL in my Chrome Driver? @GregBurghardt

Comment: You should review the docs: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Given an app.config that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="browser" value="chrome" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SeleniumServerUrl" connectionString="http://some.url/" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You should get the "browser" value like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["browser"]
```

...and the "SeleniumServerUrl" like this:

```
var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SeleniumServerUrl"].ConnectionString)
```

Please note that you need to specify what part of the app.config you are trying to fetch (AppSettings/ConnectionStrings in the above examples).

Comment: I get an error but i see where you're going with this, thanks.

Comment: @CalAtk Please let me know what is missing and I'll will edit my answer. Dont forget to contribute to the community :)

Comment: sure let me get this figured out and I’ll update you; got side tracked

Comment: First and foremost, add the values to the `AppSettings` below latter `Runtime` like the below:

Comment: @CalAtk Your comment makes no sense, I think some of your text was not included. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create "testhost.dll.config" file instead of keeping in app.config, and config file properties as "COPY ALWAYS".  That will work.

Answer (score 0):

In some MAC and latest versions of Windows operating systems, this issue has happened, and to fix it and let the configuration manager read and parse the app. config file, you should add the below lines of code in the project files by following below steps:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select edit project files
3. Write below lines  of code after (ItemGroup)
   [image]
4. Build your project
5. Run your test again